# How to get jQuery to find the first list-item, rather than all list-items?

Tags: jquery, xhtml, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I'm trying to implement a basic jQuery infinite carousel. As much for the learning process as for anything else (as a rule I'm not a fan of re-inventing wheels, but...I have to learn somehow, might as well start with the basics).

I've managed to get the list to animate left happily enough, but I'm stuck when it comes to selecting the first element of the list. I've tried to use:

```
$('ul#services > li:first');
$('ul#services > li:first-child');
$('ul#services > li').eq([0]);
```

(xhtml below),

In each case a `console.log(first)` (the `var` name used) returns all of the list-items. Am I doing something blatantly, and obviously, wrong?

The eventual plan is to clone the first `li`, append it to the parent `ul`, remove the `li` from the list and allow the list to scroll infinitely. It's just a list of services rather than links so I'm not -at the moment- planning to have scroll or left/right functionality.

Current xhtml:

(**edited to add the entirety of the current code/html**)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />

    <!--[if IE 8]>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie8.css" />

    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lte IE 7]>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7.css" />

    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
ul#services {overflow: visible; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(

            function() {

                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $('h1 > span.businessName').each(
                            function() {
                                var text = $(this).html();
                                var first_letter = text.substr(0,1);

                                if ( /[a-zA-Z]/.test(first_letter) ) {
                                    $(this).html('<span class="firstLetter">' + first_letter + '</span>' + text.slice(1));
                                }
                            }
                    ); 
            });

                $('ul#services > li').filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
                $('ul#services > li').filter(':visible:last').addClass('last');

//--> Function starts

        jQuery.fn.carousel = function() {
            // 1. find the width of the list items:

                var listWidth = $('ul#services > li').outerWidth();

            // 2a. find the current first item:

                var curFirst = $('ul#services > li').first();

                console.log(curFirst);

            // 2b. append the current first item:

            // 2c. remove the first item 

            // 3. animate the list, to move left by listWidth:

                $('ul#services > li').delay(500).css('position','relative').animate(
                    {
                    left: '-=' + listWidth
                    },
                    5000,
                        function() {

    //                      $('ul#services').get(0).remove();
                            $('ul#services').delay(500).carousel()
                        }
                );
            };
//--> Function ends.
            $('ul#services').carousel();

            }
        )

    </script>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="pageWrap">

        <div id="branding">

            <h1><span class="businessName">business name</span> <span class="tagline">some other info</span></h1>
            <hr id="rule">

        </div>

        <div id="content">

<div class="carousel">

    <div class="wrapper">

        <ul id="services">
            <li>one</li
            ><li>two</li
            ><li>three</li
            ><li>four</li
            ><li>five</li
            ><li>six</li
            ><li>seven</li
            ><li>eight</li
            ><li>nine</li
            ><li>ten</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

        </div>

        <div id="mainPane">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">

            <div id="contact">
    <!--
        STARTS hCARD (below)
    -->
                <div id="hcard">
                    <div id="hcard-yy-xx" class="vcard">
                        <span class="fn"><span class="given-name">YY</span> <span class="family-name">XX</span></span>
                        <div class="org">business name</div>
                        <a class="email" href="mailto:xx@xx.com">email</a>

                            <div class="tel">

                            </div>
                            <a class="downloadAs" href="http://suda.co.uk/projects/microformats/hcard/get-contact.php?uri=http://www.davidrhysthomas.co.uk/arch/tester.html">Download contact information</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <!--
        ENDS hCARD (above)
    -->
            </div>

            <div id="professionalBodies">

                <ul>
                    <li>some stuff</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

        <div class="push"></div>

    </div>

        <div id="footer">


        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Updated, in response to Nick Craver's answer:

> ...I believe you want: `$('ul#services li:first').remove();`
>   ...What you probably want there is something like `$('ul#services > li:first').delay(500)...`

Using `$('ul#services li:first').remove();` generates the error:

> > Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'remove'

and there seems to be no difference in behaviour from using `$('ul#services > li:first').delay(500)...`

Comment: Where are you setting first?  The selectors are correct, I'm guessing the issue is outside, can you post the code where you're setting/using it?

Comment: And I was hoping to *hide* my -to be honest- atrocious crimes against jQuery... =) Yup, I'll post the function I'm trying to harness/use. Gimme a couple seconds...

Comment: can you provide the full code?  there might be something in there that can help us.

Comment: @Nick Craver, @NickLarson: done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're learning it, I won't do all the corrections here, but here are the main points:

This is erroring: `$('ul#services').get(0).remove();`
I believe you want: `$('ul#services li:first').remove();`

This is the main reason for what you're seeing: `$('ul#services > li').delay(500)...`
This starts the animation on **each** of the child `<li>` and what you see is 10 console.log because you're kicking off carousel 10 times, 1 for each `<li>`.

What you probably want there is something like `$('ul#services > li:first').delay(500)...`

All of that make sense?  I'm not exactly sure what you want the end result to be, just trying to explain your current behavior.

Comment: Ah! I'd picked up on the `remove()` error, thanks to Google's console. The...animation issue hadn't even occurred to me. Thanks! I'm assuming , then, that I'd need to animate the `ul` rather than the descendant `li`s (I've left my mistake in my comment, but editing to note that I've caught your suggestion re animating $('ul#services > li:first')` thanks again? +1

Comment: @ricebowl - I'm not exactly sure what you want the result to be, so hard to say, you want them to scroll up or...?

Comment: Scroll left. Ideally I'm trying to clone the first list-element, append it to the list and then remove the cloned-element. Rinse and repeat...

Comment: Incidentally, using `$('ul#services').get(0).remove()` generates the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLUListElement> has no method 'remove'" in Chrome's console.

Comment: Other than the right-to-left scroll preference, that's exactly what I'm after =) thanks! +accepted!

Answer (score 4):

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

```
$('ul#services li:first)
```

is correct, your problem must be elsewhere, try `.first()` ?

Comment: Assuming you meant `var first = $('ul#services > li').first()` I can only say that it didn't work.